# copy a range to an email

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a range to copy data in excel on to an email but the below line of code will only copy one column and row.

Can anybody help me?

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Sheets("sheet1").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Comment: it takes only visible cells from range `D4:D12`. Help you with what?

Comment: want to select specific column data hence i tried with D4:D12 but it gives only headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) If you are not using Microsoft Outlook and using a manual paste option:

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set Table1 = ws1.Range("A1:D4")

    Table1.Copy

End Sub
```

Obviously change the Worksheet name and range to suite your needs and you will need to select paste in the email application you are using for the data to appear.

2) if you are using Microsoft Outlook then you can use something very similar to my code:

(NOTE: You need to ensure Microsoft Outlook is running BEFORE you run the Macro)

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim Table1 As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Table1 = ws1.Range("A1:D4").value

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .HTMLBody = Table1
        .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub



Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim FSO As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = FSO.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```